# does anyone know how to fix my error preventing me from upgrading I now have 52+9 more packages to upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade

i used sudo apt update
then sudo apt upgrade i then tried 
sudo apt install -f this is what returned

decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt

dpkg-deb: error:  subprocess returned error exit status 2

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apt_1.6.12ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):

cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/locale/cy/LC_MESSAGES/apt.mo' to '/usr/share/locale/cy/LC_MESSAGES/apt.mo.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apt_1.6.12ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please try removing the apt cache (downloaded files) first : "sudo apt autoremove" and then re-install or update whatever package you've given the error for. And please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244660/im-not-able-to-upgrade-packages-from-an-error#) your question and reformat it to make it more readable and please also post the command that you had issued before getting those errors.

Comment: I tried to do the auto remove and it still returned an error

Comment: Which version of ubuntu do you use ?

Comment: This is probably an issue with upgrading the apt package itself. It might be corrupted while being downloaded or some other issue So depending on the version you use , you should manually download and install either [this](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.0.2_amd64.deb) for ubuntu 20.04 or [this](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.1_amd64.deb) for 18.04. You should install it via "sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.1_amd64.deb" . See if the problem gets solved.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: anyone else have any ideas?